# how to parallelize Selenium2 Web Driver Junit test cases with Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit4, selenium-grid

I have a few Selenium2 test cases in java using Junit.
Test cases are executed one after the other which takes lot of time.
I want to execute those test cases parallely.